# Generalized area of a plane within a cylinder

Tags: calculus, area, surfaces

How would one determine the area of the plane $x+y+z=a$ that is contained within the cylinder $x^2+y^2=b^2$?

Comment: Cheating: the section is an ellipse of axis $b$ and $\sqrt3b$, then $\pi\sqrt3b^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. The intersection is an ellipse  whose area is given by the following integral (see [surface integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral#Surface_integrals_of_scalar_fields)):
$$\iint_{\{x^2+y^2\leq b^2\}}\sqrt{1+ f_x^2(x,y)+f_y^2(x,y)}dxdy$$
where $f(x,y)=z=a-x-y$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I think so; thank you.

Comment: From your hint, I then figured that $f_x = -1$ and $f_y=-1$, so the integral then becomes $$\int\int_\left(x^2+y^2\le b^2\right) \sqrt{1+-1^2+-1^2}dxdy$$
The integrand is simple enough; it become $\sqrt{3}$ which can be factored out of the integral.
Then I switched to polar coordinates, changing the integral into $$\sqrt{3}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^brdrd\theta$$
which becomes $\sqrt{3}\int_0^{2\pi}{b^2\over2}d\theta$
which becomes $\sqrt{3}(2\pi)\left({b^2\over2}\right)$
which finally reduces to $\sqrt{3}\pi b^2$.
Is that how it should be done?

Comment: @rohtifyer Yes. However note that $\int\int_\left(x^2+y^2\le b^2\right) 1dxdy$ is the area for the disc of radius $b$, so you get directly $\pi b^2$.